# What is the correct way to write "God bless America"?

Tags: commas

I've seen people write "God bless America", and it drives me nuts.

Shouldn't it be "God, bless America"?

Comment: Good question. But no one is commanding God to bless America! Well, I suppose some would try, but I doubt it would work out too well for them :-)

Comment: Well, it drives me nuts for other reasons than the lack of comma, but I digress...

Comment: Standing up :-)

Comment: "God Bless [Amurica](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Amurica)!"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Grammatically, I like to think of it as "May God bless America." The mood of the verb is subjunctive. The "may" is just dropped for conciseness.

Comment: +1. This is supposed to be rendered in the subjunctive. What nerve a speaker would have to use the imperative with God.

Comment: Yes, it's subjunctive with the "may" removed, certainly not imperative or addressed to God. Similar phrases with "May" dropped include, say,  "Heaven help us", "The Devil take the hindmost", or "The Force be with you" (which I've not checked is actually present in the Star Wars corpus :p).

Comment: They don't need "may" necessarily. I'd argue that the verb in these *is* in the subjunctive, though the "conjugation" isn't overt anymore. In the case of "the force be with you" or "the Holy Spirit be with you", "to be" I think is more clearly subjunctive.

Comment: It is subjunctive, and there is no “may” which has been removed—it is simply a fixed idiom that comes from a time when the subjunctive could be freely used this way.

Comment: In BE it would be "God Bless, America" in a condescending tone like a grandmother patting a small child

Comment: The formulaic subjunctive, to be more precise.

Answer (score 7):

You'll notice you also say things like, "I'd rather that he *leave* early..." (not "leaves").  You are using the subjunctive mood, which isn't grammatically overt in English all that often, but does pop up here and there.  "God bless America" is one of these cases.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Usage

Answer (score 1):

You can also write *God Bless America*, the title of a song written by Irving Berlin and made famous by singer Kate Smith.